# in MERN react, how i can send JSON data from one component to another and how to fetch it

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am developing application in MERN(Mongo, Express, React, Node).
I am navigating to another component after saving data successfully
now I want to navigate to another component with some json data, can anyone help regarding this. also let me know how to fetch json data in another component.

Here is the code from where I am navigating to /wellcomback successfully, let me know how I can send some json data to "welcome back" screen.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './header.css';

class Signup extends Component{

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {};
    }
    postSignup = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = this.email.value;
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/register/enterDetail/'+email, {
            method: 'get'
        }).then(() =>
            this.props.history.push('/wellcomback')
        ).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="main_login">
                <div className="sign_up_wrap">
                    <div className="left_side">
                        <h2>Howday!</h2>

                        <p>Go ahead and signup. This will associate your <br /> sign-up info with the profile you are claiming.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="right_side  welcm_back">
                        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                        <form action="/wellcomback">
                            <div className="pms_field">
                                <input type="email" placeholder="" ref={(r) => this.email = r} name="email" />
                                <label>Email</label>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" onClick={this.postSignup} />
                            <p>By siging up, you indicate that you have read and agree to our <a href='https://www.truebase.io/terms/'>terms and condition</a> and <a href='https://www.truebase.io/privacy/'>privacy policy</a>.</p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Signup;
```

here is my wellcomback screen where i am rendering successfully, also let me know how i can fetch data here

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './header.css';

class WellcomBack extends Component{



    render(){
        return(
            <div className="main_login">
                <div className="sign_up_wrap">
                    <div className="left_side welc_left">
                        <h2>Wellcome Back</h2>
                        <h5>Before you Login and use Truebase,</h5>
                        <p>Please setup your password and basic information.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="right_side welcm_back">
                        <form action="/skills">
                            <div className="pms_field">
                                <input type="text" />
                                <label className="default_lable">Your favourite handle</label>
                                <label className="selected_label">Truebase.io/</label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="pms_field">
                                <input type="text" />
                                <label>First Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="pms_field">
                                <input type="text" />
                                <label>Last Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="pms_field">
                                <div id="password_strength"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="pms_field">
                                <input type="password" />
                                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Proceed" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default WellcomBack;
```

Comment: I would better suggest you to use redux for the above scenario or the latest context api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send some data like this as well:

```
this.props.history.push('/wellcomback', {
  data: response.data
})
```

In the other component then:

```
console.log(this.props.location.state.data)
```

From [React Router Docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history):
`state` location-specific state that was provided to e.g. `push(path, state)` when this location was pushed onto the stack. Only available in browser and memory history.